Proving a spline solves the TV-regularisation problem
So I am currently reading Mammen's and van de Geer's Locally Adaptive Regression Splines (published in the Annals of Statistics, 1997, Vol. 25, No. 1, p 387-413). In it, the authors introduce the following function to minimise
$$
F_{k,\lambda}(m) = \sum_{i=1}^n(Y_i - m(x_i))^2 + \lambda \mathrm{TV}(m^{(k-1})
$$
used to find an interpolating function of the (noisy) dataset $Y_1,\dots,Y_n$, which stems from sampling a function $y$ at the points $x_i\in [0,1]$. Here $\mathrm{TV}$ is the total-variaton of $m$, which for splines of order $k$ with knots $t_1,\dots,t_p$ is given as $\mathrm{TV}(m^{(k-1)}) = \sum_{i=2}^p |m^{(k-1)}(t_i) - m^{(k-1)}(t_{i-1})|$
A bit further down, they introduce the notation
$$
 H(m, t) = 2\sum_{i=1}^n m(x_i) (x_i-t)_+^{k-1} \text{ and } H(Y,t) = 2\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i(x_i-t)_+^{k-1}
$$
where $a_+$ denotes the positive part of $a$. Using this, they state

A spline $m$ of order $k$, with knot-points $t_1,\dots,t_p$ minimises $F_{k,\lambda}$ iff

$|H(m, t) - H(Y,t)| \leq (k-1)!\lambda$ for all $t$,
for $m^{(k-1)}(t_j-) < m^{(k-1)}(t_j+)$ we have $H(m,t_j) = H(Y,t_j) - (k-1)!\lambda$
for $m^{(k-1)}(t_j-) > m^{(k-1)}(t_j+)$ we have $H(m,t_j) = H(Y,t_j) + (k-1)!\lambda$
for $q=0,\dots,k-1$ it holds that $\sum_{i=1}^k (Y_i - m(x_i))x_i^q = 0$


As proof they show that small peturbations of such an $m$ increase $F_{k,\lambda}$, therefore $m$ is a local minimiser ($F_{k,\lambda}$ is convex). These peturbations are of the form
$$
m_{\delta,t}(x) = m(x) + \delta(x-t)_+^{k-1}.
$$
Following this, they claim that it suffices to show that for all $t$ $F_{k,\lambda}(m_{\delta,t}) \geq F_{k,\lambda}(m)$ where $|\delta|$ is sufficiently small based on the fact that
$$
\mathrm{TV}(m_{\delta,t}^{(k-1)}) = \mathrm{TV}(m^{(k-1)}) + \begin{cases}|\delta| & t \text{ is no knot-point}\\
-\delta(k-1)! & t=t_j \text{ and } m^{(k-1)}(t_j-) > m^{(k-1)}(t_j+)\\
\delta(k-1)! & t=t_j \text{ and } m^{(k-1)}(t_j-) < m^{(k-1)}(t_j+)
\end{cases}.
$$
I managed to prove why $\mathrm{TV}(m_{\delta,t}^{(k-1)})$ is of this form, however
I don't see why the calculation above shows that $F_{k,\lambda}(m_{\delta,t}) \geq F_{k,\lambda}(m)$.

Have a look to this paper by M. Unser who is recognized as a top researcher in this domain.
